# angular fire 2 error when retrieving item from fire base with key

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

When I try to retrieve a item from Firebase using the items key in this format, I receive this error.

```
getUser(id: string){
  console.log("current user id: " +  id);
  const user = this.af.database.object(`/userData/${id}`);
  this.userFromDb = this.af.database.object(`/userData/${id}`);
  user.subscribe(console.log);
  console.log("object from db: " + this.userFromDb);
  return this.userFromDb;
}
```

> Error: database.refFromURL failed: First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".

Comment: Please include the output from `console.log("current user id: " +  id);` It's obvious from the error that the path passed to `object()` contains invalid characters.

Comment: It seems that `/userData/${id}` is not parsed into an interpolated string before querying firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the error message `$` is invalid. 
Firebase fully supports URL like path so this should work:

```
const user = this.af.database.object('/userData/' + id);
```